# Is there any way to open a new tab using a webbrowser module of python in colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, python-webbrowser

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.google.com')
```

I am using Google-colaboratory and getting False as a output. Instead of that, it should open a new tab with url of Google. It's working well in python 3.7 as well as in PyCharm.

I know that program written in colab runs on google cloud and there's nothing like browser in google cloud.

Is there any other way to do this in google-colab except by using selenium tools?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to control your browser via Python's `webbrowser` package in Colab. The reason is that your browser is running on your local machine, while the Python code in Colab is running on a virtual machine in Google Cloud.

The only way you can open a new tab via Colab is by injecting javascript code that will cause your browser to do so; for example:

```
%%javascript
window.open('https://colab.research.google.com', '_blank');
```

But be aware that your browser may block windows opened in this manner.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes if the lines of code required to open a webpage need to be enclosed in conditional statements or a loop or any situation in which %%javascript cannot be written as first line of the cell, use this code

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
def open_web():
    url = 'https://www.google.com/'
    display(Javascript('window.open("{url}");'.format(url=url)))
```

Comment: Precisely my usecase.

Comment: The same note still apply: "But be aware that your browser may block windows opened in this manner." Navigate on the address bar, unblock the blocked site.